# Highlighting a button in windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm making a windows form application that has a timeline not to different from one found in video editing software.

The controls on this time line are a custom class that inherits Button.

I want the user to be able to click the button once to select it (highlighted) and once again to unselect it. This is so the user can select several timeline items at once.

Is there any way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well actually you would be better off with CheckBox control and you can make it look just like regular button:

[image]

Note that you can assign each button with a different 'Group' property so that each one of them can be separately check or unchecked.

Comment: This is fantastic. I don't suppose you could provide a brief explanation of how you got the checkboxes looking like that?

Comment: Just add a checkbox to the form and change the "Appearance" property to "Button" then you can modify the color etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. May be more suitable solution to you is create a derived control from **RadioButton** or **CheckBox**, that stores Pressed/Checked **state** information.
2. If you can not, for 1000 of reasons that could be, you can add **state** management to your custom Button class.

Hope this helps.

Regards.